# How to map a DynamoDB Streams object to a Javascript object?

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a Lambda trigger hooked up to DynamoDB Streams. The relevant DynamoDB document is passed to the Lambda object as an [AttributeValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_AttributeValue.html).

My Lambda function looks like this:

```
import { Handler, Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda'
import { config, DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk'

const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
  if (!event) {
    return callback(null, `Failed processing records. event is null.`);
  }
  if (!event.Records) {
    return callback(null, `Failed processing records. No records present.`);
  }
  event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    console.log(record.eventID);
    console.log(record.eventName);
    console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
    //An example of record.dynamodb is shown below.
  });
  return callback(null, `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`);
}

export { handler }
```

An example of the AttributeValue looks like this:

```
{
  "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1554660820,
  "Keys": {
    "id": {
      "S": "ab66eb3e-045e-41d6-9633-75597cd47234"
    },
    "date_time": {
      "S": "2019-04-07T18:13:40.084Z"
    }
  },
  "NewImage": {
    "some_property": {
      "S": "some data"
    },
    "another_property": {
      "S": "more data"
    },
    "id": {
      "S": "ab66eb3e-045e-41d6-9633-75597cd47234"
    },
    "date_time": {
      "S": "2019-04-07T18:13:40.084Z"
    }
  },
  "SequenceNumber": "60215400000000011976585954",
  "SizeBytes": 1693,
  "StreamViewType": "NEW_IMAGE"
}
```

How do I map the AttributeValue to a javascript object, preferably using a Typescript definition? I.e. if I define a Typescript class like this:

```
class DynamoDBDocument {
    id: string;
    date_time: Date;
    some_property: string
    another_property: string
}
```

it would result in an object like this:

```
{
    "id": "ab66eb3e-045e-41d6-9633-75597cd47234",
    "date_time": "S": "2019-04-07T18:13:40.084Z",
    "some_property": "some data",
    "another_property": "more data"
}
```

[DynamoDB Data Mapper](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js) looks like a promising solution, but I can't figure out how to use it with the AttributeValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [@shiftcoders/dynamo-easy](https://github.com/shiftcode/dynamo-easy):

First define your model (make sure to define the correct [date mapper](https://shiftcode.gitbook.io/dynamo-easy/api/model/decorators#dateproperty-options) if anything other than ISO string is required)

```
import { DateProperty, Model, PartitionKeyUUID, SortKey } from '@shiftcoders/dynamo-easy'

@Model({ tableName: 'dynamo-table-name' })
class CustomModel {
  // hash key with auto generated uuid
  @PartitionKeyUUID()
  id: string

  // range key
  @SortKey()
  @DateProperty()
  date_time: Date

  some_property: string
  another_property: string
}
```

implement the handler function

```
import { DateProperty, fromDb, Model, PartitionKeyUUID, SortKey } from '@shiftcoders/dynamo-easy'
import { Callback, Context } from 'aws-lambda'
import * as DynamoDB from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb'
import { Handler } from 'aws-sdk/clients/lambda'

const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
  event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    const newImage: DynamoDB.AttributeMap = record.dynamodb.NewImage
    if (newImage) {
      // map the dynamoDB attributes to a JS object using the CustomModel
      const newObject = fromDb(newImage, CustomModel)
      console.log(`item with id ${newObject.id} / ${newObject.date_time.toDateString()} changed to %j`, newObject)

      // start with the business logic which requires the newObject
    }

  })

  // no need to use callback when using async handler
  return `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`
}
```

Checkout the docs for more information on how to execute [requests](https://shiftcode.gitbook.io/dynamo-easy/api/dynamo-store/model-requests) if eventually required by your business logic.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! Only thing is the compiler complains: "Argument of type 'AttributeMap' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, Attribute>'". But it does work if I cast 'newImage' to <any> (not ideal).

Comment: Better cast to `Attributes` like this `fromDb(<Attributes>newImage, CustomModel)`  (or even `Attributes<CustomModel>`). We internally use `Attributes<T>` instead of `DynamoDB.AttributeMap` for better typing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [DynamoDB Data Marshaller](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/tree/master/packages/dynamodb-data-marshaller).

```
import { Handler, Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda'
import { AttributeMap } from "aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb";
import { DataMapper } from '@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper'
import { unmarshallItem, Schema } from '@aws/dynamodb-data-marshaller'

const someSchema: Schema = {
    id: {type: 'String', keyType: "HASH"},
    date_time: {type: 'Date', keyType: "RANGE"},
    some_property: {type: 'String'},
    another_property: {type: 'String'},
};

const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {

  event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    let dynamoDB: AttributeMap = record.dynamodb.NewImage
    let someObject = unmarshallItem(someSchema, dynamoDB)
    console.log('DynamoDB Object: %j', someObject)

  });
  return callback(null, `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`);
}

export { handler }
```

Comment: This is outdated in 2020... It has not been updated for 2+ years

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way I found is to use the unmarshall function from the `aws-sdk` package. It looks something like this;

```
import { Converter } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';

...

const record = Converter.unmarshall(AttributeValue); 
// where AttributeValue is the ddb stream record
```